# Docker rebuilding image from first ADD

Tags: docker

Docker is re-building my image, from the first ADD, *every time* even when I make no changes to it.

It is very simple:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

RUN mkdir /cassandra

ADD https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.9/apache-cassandra-3.9-bin.tar.gz /tmp/cassandra.tar.gz

RUN tar -xf /tmp/cassandra.tar.gz -C /cassandra && rm /tmp/cassandra.tar.gz

EXPOSE 9042
```

And it keeps running the ADD, and everything after it, every time I build. The ADD takes about a while so it is very difficult.

Comment: See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use

```
apk add --no-cache wget && \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    wget your_website.html && \                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ..
    Do some stuff
    ..                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    apk del --no-cache wget
```

This accomplishes exactly what *I* needed. ADD re-downloads every time and there's seemingly nothing we can do about that according to @maxm's link

Answer (score 0):

Docker isn't sure if the link has changed or not, it has no way to check the contents of the request. (I mean, it could check of a hash of the contents, but it would still have to download the file). You should download the file yourself and copy it into the build directly.

Some discussion: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3672#issuecomment-63335989